# Excel Formula Based on Column Value

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that has about 1,200 job items. Each job item is assigned to a Task number (its own column, i.e., Task 1, Task 2, Task 3, etc). Each job item includes columns for $ committed, $ obligated, and $ expense. I need a formula that will give me a total for each Task number based on the 3 $ columns for all 1,200 rows. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but I think the sum formula would work.

Depending on the column arrangement, use a formula like this:

=SUM(E5:H5)

Answer (score 0):

You have options, for example extract a list of unique tasks (say with Advanced Filter, Copy to another location, say G2 etc) and a formula such as:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,G2,C:C)+SUMIF(B:B,G2,D:D)+SUMIF(B:B,G2,E:E)
```

copied down to suit.

Or with a PivotTable and a Calculated Field. `Task` column in ROWS, Sum of each of the `$` columns in VALUES and a field added of:

```
='$Committed' +'$ expense' +'$obligated'
```